# Have error output include last couple lines of code

Tags: c++, error-handling, gnu, output, m4

Is it possible, and if so, how would you make error output include the last couple lines of code? I know about GNU g++'s support for `__LINE__` and `__FUNC__` but those only give the line number as an int and the function name as a string - I'd like to dump the function that failed's code or at least the last several commands executed by the program.

I was thinking maybe write a m4 script that would parse through the code base and inject string structures of the functions they're put in (excluding themselves, of course).

Any other/better ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "dump the function that failed's code"? Isn't that what `__func__` (or GCCs `__FUNCTION__`) does, get you the function name? Do you want the function _call stack_?

Comment: I want to output the full code of the function itself, or at least a couple of lines executed before the error was caught, rather than just its name.

Comment: So you want to implement a debugger that can debug itself?

Comment: I guess that's a way of saying it.

Comment: You may be able to use the GNU libc function [`backtrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace) to get the function call-stack, and use it together with [libdwarf](http://reality.sgiweb.org/davea/dwarf.html) to get debugging information from your executable (if built with debug information of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change your code at all.  Use `__LINE__` and `__FUNC__` and post process the error output.  That is, run your program as `my-prog > $(tty) 2>&1 | post-process` where `post-process` has access to your code base and can generate the desired text.  You might want to modify the code slightly by adding tags to make it easier for post-process to find the function name and line number.